# Jenkins service not able to connect without nodeport

Tags: kubernetes, devops, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

In our bare metal server `Kubernetes-v.1.19.16` has been installed, Further i have deployed jenkins service inside cluster and able to connect jenkins application URL - `http://jenkins.company.com:40200`. But not able to connect using `http://jenkins.company.com/jenkins`

I have below `service` and `ingress` resource config files to connect without node port.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: jenkins-svc
  namespace: jenkins
  annotations:
      prometheus.io/scrape: 'true'
      prometheus.io/path:   /
      prometheus.io/port:   '8080'
spec:
  selector: 
    app: jenkins-server
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - name: jenkins
      port: 8080
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 8080
      nodePort: 40200
    - name: jnlp
      port: 50000
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 50000
```

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: jenkins-ingress
  namespace: jenkins
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  rules:
    - host: jenkins.company.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /jenkins
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
               service:
                name: jenkins-svc
                port:
                  number: 8080
```

Service status:-

```
kubectl get services -n jenkins
NAME          TYPE       CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                          AGE
jenkins-svc   NodePort   10.104.208.49   <none>        8080:40200/TCP,50000:31922/TCP   15h
```

Ingress status:-

```
# kubectl get ingress -n jenkins
Warning: extensions/v1beta1 Ingress is deprecated in v1.14+, unavailable in v1.22+; use networking.k8s.io/v1 Ingress
NAME              CLASS    HOSTS                 ADDRESS   PORTS   AGE
jenkins-ingress   <none>   jenkins.compnay.com             80      21h
```

```
$ kubectl describe ingress jenkins-ingress -n jenkins
Warning: extensions/v1beta1 Ingress is deprecated in v1.14+, unavailable in v1.22+; use networking.k8s.io/v1 Ingress
Name:             jenkins-ingress
Namespace:        jenkins
Address:
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (<error: endpoints "default-http-backend" not found>)
Rules:
  Host             Path  Backends
  ----             ----  --------
  jenkins.company.com
                   /jenkins(/|$)(.*)   jenkins-svc:8080 (10.244.0.23:8080)
Annotations:       nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
Events:            <none>
```

On browser when i tried connect `http://jenkins.compnay.com/jenkins` it says below errors.

```
Not Found

The requested URL was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.54 (Ubuntu) Server at jenkins.company.com Port 80
```

On cluster getting below given connection error.

```
$ curl jenkins.company.com/jenkins
curl: (7) Failed to connect to jenkins.company.com port 80: Connection refused

$ curl jenkins.company.com:8080/jenkins
curl: (7) Failed to connect to jenkins.company.com port 8080: Connection refused
```

Please suggest what's wrong with my configuration? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to change the rewrite logic similar to the example in the docs.
Because the Error message seems to come from the jenkins pod, because its apache 404, not nginx you use as proxy.

https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/#examples

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
  name: jenkins-ingress
  namespace: jenkins
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: jenkins.company.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /jenkins(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: jenkins-svc
            port: 
              number: 8080
```

Comment: Still experiencing the same problem `kubectl describe ingress jenkins-ingress -n jenkins` output added in question.